# UIViewControllers not receiving orientation notifications

Tags: cocoa-touch, ipad, orientation

I've spent the last hour or so trying to work out why not all my UIViewControllers are receiving orientation change notifications.

I've got a subclassed UIViewController attached to the window, that internally creates a few other UIViewControllers to manage smaller portions of the screen which are re-used elsewhere in the application I'm building.

The problem is, only the UIViewController attached to the window is receiving the orientation change notifications.
The other UIViewControllers aren't firing their `- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration` methods.

I'm assuming it's expected behaviour, and I can't seem to find anything mentioning it in the docs.

Is there a way to make sure all active UIViewControllers are getting orientation changes? Or does the parent view controller have to tell it's children when changes are occurring?

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are all your view controllers returning YES to shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation: ? If so, I suggest to pass the interface orientation messages from the parent to the children viewControllers, as you suggested.

I have been doing so before and had no problems with that approach so far.